# How to use reationships without migrations in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-relations

I am using laravel framework to develop apis.we are not using migration files instead of that one we are hardcoding table name in models,is there any chance i can use relationships without migrations.

Let’s consider user hasMany books in this scenario how can i relate them in model.

**Users table**
u_id ,u_name ,u_role

**books table**
b_id, b_uid ,b_name

Note:- u_id is related to b_uid

Comment: Put some effort and study that in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships). Hint: also check "One To Many" section of the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations and models are not related in any way. Migrations are needed to make changes to the database structure. If you change the database structure in any other way, this should not interfere with the use of models and relationships

```
class Book extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'b_id';

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'b_uid', 'u_id');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'u_id';

    public function books(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class, 'b_uid', 'u_id');
    }
}
```